# Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 1:undefined:-1 Invalid function 'replace'

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, impala, hue

I am using HIVE

I keep receiving the error message below whenever I run my code:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 1:undefined:-1 Invalid function 'replace'
```

Here is my code:

```
select 
ecat.count_category, eact.count_eventaction, elabel.count_eventlabel,
g.*,h.*  from db1.table1 g 
join (select count(distinct eventcategory) count_category, g.session_id from db1.table1 g group by g.session_id ) ecat on ecat.session_id = g.session_id
join (select count(distinct eventaction) count_eventaction,  g.session_id from db1.table1 g group by g.session_id) eact on eact.session_id = g.session_id
join (select count(distinct eventlabel) count_eventlabel, g.session_id from db1.table1 g group by g.session_id ) elabel on elabel.session_id = g.session_id
join (select replace(h.display_name, '\'', '') display_name, h.ncct_cat, h.ncct_cat_cd, h.ncct_trmnt_id, h.oop_proc_cd, replace(h.oop_diag_cd, '\'','') oop_diag_cd from db2.table2 h  
  where replace(h.display_name, '\'', '') =  'Ultrasound, Abdomen (Complete)' and 
   replace(h.client_code, '\'', '')='MASTER' ) h on 
   replace(h.display_name, '\'', '') = g.eventLabel and g.eventAction='ENCOUNTER';
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to why I keep receiving this error message? I am using HIVE.

Comment: It should be regexp_replace not replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive [replace](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13063) function is introduced starting from 1.3.0 version.

```
select replace(string("kkl'll"),'\'','')="kk";
false
```

Please **check the hive version** you are using in your environment.

To workaround this issue use **`regexp_replace`** fucntion.

```
select regexp_replace(string("kkl'll"),'\'','')="kk";
false
```

Comment: I am using Hive 2.1. Also it is still giving me a error regarding replace. Could you chat by any chance?

Comment: Ok.. let's continue in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194548/general chat now..!!